# Passing locale via header or URL param are not changing the rails default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

When i'm trying to make a request passing the param locale, i18n are not changing the default locale

ApplicationController

```
before_filter :set_locale
respond_to :json

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

My Model

```
class FoodType < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope where(locale: I18n.locale)
```

FoodTypesController

```
def index   
  render json: FoodType.all
end
```

But in the console, the query doesnt change. Still passing the locale from previous request

```
passing locale = pt-BR 

FoodType Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "food_types".* FROM "food_types" WHERE "food_types"."locale" = 'en'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scope is evaluated when the FoodType class is loaded. This means that it will always have the same (initial) value. You need to use a lambda for scopes like this that vary depending on some external variable (time is another example):

```
default_scope, lambda { where(locale: I18n.locale) }
```